# WebGL: smoothly fade lines out of canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I'm a beginner at WebGL programming.

I've made a web application in Three.JS that draws a sin wave onto a canvas with occasional noise. After they've been drawn, I fade them away. The final effect looks something like this:

[image]

I'm trying to make the application in WebGL because of speed issues with Three.JS. I am able to draw one plain sin wave in WebGL but don't know how to achieve the same effect where I can draw a single wave, keep it in the buffer somehow, and fade it away.

This is what I currently have (in WebGL):

[image]

Also, here is the relevant code:

```
    this.gl;
    try {
        this.gl = this.canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl',{antialias: false});
    } catch (e) {
        alert('WebGL not supported.');
    }

    //set position of vertices in clip coordinates
    this.vtxShaderSrc = "\n\
    attribute vec2 position;\n\
    uniform vec2 viewport;\n\
    \n\
    void main(void){\n\
        \n\
        gl_Position = vec4((position/viewport)*2.0-1.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n\
    }";
    //fragment shader returns the color of pixel
    this.fmtShaderSrc = "\n\
    precision mediump float;\n\
    \n\
    \n\
    \n\
    void main(void){\n\
        int r = 255;\n\
        int g = 255;\n\
        int b = 255;\n\
        gl_FragColor = vec4(r/255,g/255,b/255,1.);\n\
    }";

    this.getShader = function(source, type){
        var shader = this.gl.createShader(type);
        this.gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
        this.gl.compileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }

    this.vtxShader = this.getShader(this.vtxShaderSrc, this.gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    this.fmtShader = this.getShader(this.fmtShaderSrc, this.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    this.program = this.gl.createProgram();
    //attach fragment and vertex shader to program
    this.gl.attachShader(this.program, this.vtxShader); 
    this.gl.attachShader(this.program, this.fmtShader);
    //link program to WebGL
    this.gl.linkProgram(this.program);
    //get position attribute and enable it in vertex shader
    this._position = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'position');
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this._position);
    //tell WebGL to use this program
    this.gl.useProgram(this.program);
    //create buffers
    this.vertexBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.facesBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();

    this.lineVertices = [];
    this.faceCount = [];
    //bind them to WebGL
    this.bindVertexBuffer = function(){
        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBuffer);
        this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.lineVertices), this.gl.STREAM_DRAW);
    }
    this.bindFacesBuffer = function(){
        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.facesBuffer);
        this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(this.faceCount), this.gl.STREAM_DRAW);     
    }
    this.bindVertexBuffer();
    this.bindFacesBuffer();
    //set background color to black
    this.gl.clearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    //draw on canvas



    this.draw = function(){
        this.gl.enable(this.gl.BLEND);


        this.gl.viewport(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._position, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 8*2, 0);

        var loc = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'viewport');
        this.gl.uniform2f(loc, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

        //draw only if number of lines is greater than 0
        if(this.faceCount.length > 0){
            this.gl.drawElements(this.gl.LINE_STRIP, this.faceCount.length/4, this.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        }


        this.gl.disable(this.gl.BLEND);
    } 

    //update vertices and faces so next call to this.draw() updates the wave
    this.update = function(newPts){
        this.lineVertices = newPts;
        this.bindVertexBuffer();
        var faces = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.lineVertices.length; i++)   faces.push(i);
        this.faceCount = faces;
        this.bindFacesBuffer();
    }
```

Any help/pointers are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Interesting. What was the bottleneck for the three.js implementation, if I may ask?

Comment: @user01 the method I use to render the lines in three.js draws extra lines and applies a lower opacity as more lines are drawn. It works just fine for one, even two waves (say sin and cos wave). However, I plan on having many many more waves overlapping on one canvas. This starts to drop the FPS significantly, as number of incoming points increases to tens of thousands. Directly dealing with WebGL apparently increases this performance by 20-50 times. I'm trying to mimic the rendering method used by this person:  http://codeflow.org/entries/2013/feb/04/high-performance-js-heatmaps/

Comment: Track a brightness variable or something similiar. It should start at 1.0, then decrease it to 0 as time passes. Send it to the GPU and multiply `gl_FragColor` by the brightness. Its also possible to move the brightness decrease entirely to GPU but Im not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to give an answer as there's [an infinite number of ways to do it](https://www.vertexshaderart.com/art/ctdaXFjXNjTiss8Kh) but basically WebGL is just a rasteration API so if you want something to fade out overtime you have to render it every frame and over time draw things you want to fade out with a more transparency.

In pseudo code

```
 for each thing to draw
    compute its age
    draw more transparent the older it is
    (optionally, delete it if it's too old)
```

Here's a canvas 2d version to keep it simple

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d")
var currentTime = 0;  // in seconds
var ageLimit = 1;  // 1 second
var birthDuration = 0.2; // 0.2 seconds
var birthTimer = 0;
var thingsToDraw = [];

function addThingToDraw() {
  thingsToDraw.push({
    timeOfBirth: currentTime,
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random(),
  });
}

function computeAge(thing) {
  return currentTime - thing.timeOfBirth;
}

function removeOldThings() {
  while(thingsToDraw.length > 0) {
    var age = computeAge(thingsToDraw[0]);
    if (age < ageLimit) {
      break;
    }
    // remove thing that's too old
    thingsToDraw.shift();
  }
}

function drawThings() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  
  thingsToDraw.forEach(function(thing) {
    var age = computeAge(thing);
    var lerp = age / ageLimit;
    var x = ctx.canvas.width * thing.x;
    var y = ctx.canvas.height * thing.y;
    var radius = 10 + lerp * 10;  // 10 to 20
    var color = makeCSSRGBAColor(0, 0, 0, 1. - lerp);
    drawCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, color);
  });
}

function drawCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

function makeCSSRGBAColor(r, g, b, a) {
  return "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")";
}

var then = 0;
function process(time) {
  currentTime = time * 0.001;
  var deltaTime = currentTime - then;
  then = currentTime;
  
  birthTimer -= deltaTime;
  if (birthTimer <= 0) {
    addThingToDraw();
    birthTimer = birthDuration;
  }
  
  removeOldThings();
  drawThings();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(process);
}
requestAnimationFrame(process);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

WebGL is no different, just replace `ctx.clearRect` with `gl.clear` and `drawCircle` with some function that draws a circle.

Here's the WebGL version of the same program

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl")
var currentTime = 0;  // in seconds
var ageLimit = 1;  // 1 second
var birthDuration = 0.2; // 0.2 seconds
var birthTimer = 0;
var thingsToDraw = [];

var vs = `
attribute vec4 position;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
}
`;

var fs = `
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
`;

var program = twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);
var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");

// make a circle of triangles
var numAround = 60;
var verts = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numAround; ++i) {
  addPoint(verts, i / numAround, 1);
  addPoint(verts, (i + 1) / numAround, 1);
  addPoint(verts, i / numAround, 0);
}
var numVerts = verts.length / 2;
var buf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


function addPoint(verts, angleZeroToOne, radius) {
  var angle = angleZeroToOne * Math.PI * 2;
  verts.push(Math.cos(angle) * radius, Math.sin(angle) * radius);
}

function addThingToDraw() {
  thingsToDraw.push({
    timeOfBirth: currentTime,
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random(),
  });
}

function computeAge(thing) {
  return currentTime - thing.timeOfBirth;
}

function removeOldThings() {
  while(thingsToDraw.length > 0) {
    var age = computeAge(thingsToDraw[0]);
    if (age < ageLimit) {
      break;
    }
    // remove thing that's too old
    thingsToDraw.shift();
  }
}

function drawThings() {
  gl.clear(gl.CLEAR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  thingsToDraw.forEach(function(thing) {
    var age = computeAge(thing);
    var lerp = age / ageLimit;
    var x = gl.canvas.width * thing.x;
    var y = gl.canvas.height * thing.y;
    var radius = 10 + lerp * 10;  // 10 to 20
    var color = [0, 0, 0, 1 - lerp];
    drawCircle(gl, x, y, radius, color);
  });
}

function drawCircle(gl, x, y, radius, color) {
  var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  var matrix = [
    2 / gl.canvas.width * radius, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 2 / gl.canvas.height * radius, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    x / gl.canvas.width * 2 - 1, y / gl.canvas.height * 2 - 1, 0, 1,
  ];  

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);
  gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, color);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVerts);
}

 function ortho(width, height) {
  return [
    2 / (width), 0, 0, 0,
    0, 2 / (height), 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    (width) / (-width), (height) / (-height), -1, 1,
  ];
}

    
var then = 0;
function process(time) {
  currentTime = time * 0.001;
  var deltaTime = currentTime - then;
  then = currentTime;
  
  birthTimer -= deltaTime;
  if (birthTimer <= 0) {
    addThingToDraw();
    birthTimer = birthDuration;
  }
  
  removeOldThings();
  drawThings();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(process);
}
requestAnimationFrame(process);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

I didn't want to include a matrix library but [you can read about matrices here](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) and because almost everyone into issues when graduating from one shape/shader to 2 you probably want to [read this about drawing multiple things](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)

Comment: thanks for such an elaborate answer. I'm going to try and implement this in my project. The first link you provided is the exact effect I'm looking for, by the way. Also, in your WebGL `process` function, does the `time` get passed in automatically? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: `process` is called by `requestAnimationFrame`. `reqeustAnimationFrame` passes the time since the page loaded in milliseconds to the function it calls

Comment: perfect. Thanks very much!