# WebGL: fade drawing buffer

Tags: webgl

I've set `preserveDrawingBuffer` to `true`.
Doing this results in everything drawn on the buffer to be seen all at once, however, 
I was wondering if there is a way to somehow fade the buffer as time goes on so that the old elements drawn disappear over time, and the newest drawn elements appear with a relatively high opacity until they also fade away.

Is there a better way to achieve such an effect?

I've tried to render previous elements again by lowering their opacity until it reaches 0 but it didn't seem like an efficient way of fading as once something is drawn I don't plan on changing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually common it just redraw stuff which I went over here

[WebGL: smoothly fade lines out of canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339215/webgl-smoothly-fade-lines-out-of-canvas/38345958#38345958)

Redrawing stuff means you can keep some things from not fading out. For example if you're making a space shooting game and you only want explosions and missile trails to fade out but you don't want the spaceships and asteroids to fade out then you need to do it by redrawing everything and manually fading stuff out by drawn them while decreasing their alpha

If you just want everything to fade out then you can use a post processing type effect.

You make 2 textures and attach them to 2 framebuffers. You blend/fade the first framebuffer `fadeFb1` into the second one `fadeFb2` with a fadeColor using

```
gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, fadeColor, mixAmount);
```

You then draw any new stuff to `fadeFb2`

Then finally draw `fadeFb2` to the canvas so you can see the result.

The next frame you do the same thing except swap which buffer you're drawing to and which one you're fading to.

```
frame 0: mix(fadeFb1,fadeColor)->fadeFb2, draw->fadeFb2, fadeFB2->canvas
frame 1: mix(fadeFb2,fadeColor)->fadeFb1, draw->fadeFb1, fadeFB1->canvas
frame 2: mix(fadeFb1,fadeColor)->fadeFb2, draw->fadeFb2, fadeFB2->canvas
...
```

Note you don't clear when you draw since you need the result to be left behind

As for setting up framebuffers there's a tutorial here that might be useful

http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html

Here's an example using [twgl](http://twgljs.org) since I'm too lazy for straight WebGL

```js
var vs = `
attribute vec4 position;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
}
`;

var fs = `
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
`;
var vsQuad = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = texcoord;
}
`;
var fsFade = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float u_mixAmount;
uniform vec4 u_fadeColor;

void main() {
  vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
  gl_FragColor = mix(color, u_fadeColor, u_mixAmount);
}
`;
var fsCopy = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
`;

var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

var mixAmount = 0.05;
var mixElem = $("#mix");
var mixValueElem = $("#mixValue");
mixElem.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    setMixAmount(e.target.value / 100);
});

function setMixAmount(value) {
  mixAmount = value;
  mixValueElem.innerHTML = mixAmount;
}
setMixAmount(mixAmount);

var gl = $("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
var fadeProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vsQuad, fsFade]);
var copyProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vsQuad, fsCopy]);

// Creates a -1 to +1 quad
var quadBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);

// Creates an RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture and depth buffer framebuffer
var imgFbi = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl);

// Creates 2 RGBA texture + depth framebuffers
var fadeAttachments = [
  { format: gl.RGBA, min: gl.NEAREST, max: gl.NEAREST, wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE, },
  { format: gl.DEPTH_STENCIL },
];
var fadeFbi1 = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl, fadeAttachments);
var fadeFbi2 = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl, fadeAttachments);

function drawThing(gl, x, y, rotation, scale, color) {
  var matrix = m4.ortho(0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0, -1, 1);
  matrix = m4.translate(matrix, [x, y, 0]);
  matrix = m4.rotateZ(matrix, rotation);
  matrix = m4.scale(matrix, [scale, scale, 1]);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, quadBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    u_matrix: matrix,
    u_color: color,
  });
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, quadBufferInfo);
}

function rand(min, max) {
  if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
}

function render(time) {
  if (twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas)) {
    twgl.resizeFramebufferInfo(gl, fadeFbi1, fadeAttachments);
    twgl.resizeFramebufferInfo(gl, fadeFbi2, fadeAttachments);
  }
  
  // fade by copying from fadeFbi1 into fabeFbi2 using mixAmount.
  // fadeFbi2 will contain mix(fadeFb1, u_fadeColor, u_mixAmount)
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, fadeFbi2);

  gl.useProgram(fadeProgramInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, fadeProgramInfo, quadBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(fadeProgramInfo, {
    u_texture: fadeFbi1.attachments[0],
    u_mixAmount: mixAmount,
    u_fadeColor: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  });
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, quadBufferInfo);

  // now draw new stuff to fadeFb2. Notice we don't clear!
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, fadeFbi2);

  var x = rand(gl.canvas.width);
  var y = rand(gl.canvas.height);
  var rotation = rand(Math.PI);
  var scale = rand(10, 20);
  var color = [rand(1), rand(1), rand(1), 1];
  drawThing(gl, x, y, rotation, scale, color);


  // now copy fadeFbi2 to the canvas so we can see the result
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, null);

  gl.useProgram(copyProgramInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, copyProgramInfo, quadBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(copyProgramInfo, {
    u_texture: fadeFbi2.attachments[0],
  });
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, quadBufferInfo);

  // swap the variables so we render to the opposite textures next time
  var temp = fadeFbi1;
  fadeFbi1 = fadeFbi2;
  fadeFbi2 = temp;

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { display: block; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
#ui { position: absolute; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="ui">
<span>mix:</span><input id="mix" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="5" /><span id="mixValue"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks again for your answer! I understand redrawing stuff is common but since this program will be on an FPGA board, I need it to be as efficient & small as possible. Your twgl example is exactly what I'm looking for, however I have another question! Since I'm drawing `LINE_STRIP` instead of `TRIANGLES` would I just change the drawing mode or would that not work with the quad buffer?

Comment: ^ scratch that, I followed your example and was able to get the method working, however the lines look super pixelated for some reason. Check http://i.imgur.com/dQCG5dH.png. Changing `fbi` size to 512 makes it better

Comment: I never know how much stuff irrelevant to the question asked to add to the answer. You didn't ask about resizing the canvas and making the framebuffers match new sizes so I didn't put that code in. It's updated now to resize to fill the window

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just very new to WebGL and I don't know what affects what. But you've been an amazing help thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The `preserveDrawingBuffer` flag is useful on a device with limited memory (mobile phones) as it allows those devices to reuse that chunk of memory.

The fading/ghosting effect is done in a different manner: you allocate a texture with the same size as the viewport and do the darkening on this texture instead. Every frame you re-render the contents of this texture to itself while multiplying the color value with a fading factor (say 0.9). Afterwards, on the same texture you render your new elements and finally you render the texture to the viewport (a simple "copy-render").

Comment: Oh I see... As I'm a relative beginner to WebGL, I was wondering if you knew of any tutorials I can look at to achieve that result?

Comment: `preserveDrawingBuffer` has nothing to do with saving memory. `preserveDrawingBuffer` was added specifically because NOT preserving it is faster on some mobile devices.