# WebGL – Use mesh as mask for background image

Tags: html, background, webgl, mask, mesh

I have the following problem to solve with WebGL:

Imagine a mesh in front of the camera. The mesh is not actually shaded but its "silhouette" as a whole is used to reveal a background image as some sort of mask or stencil if you will. So e.g. you would have an output image with a white background and a silhouette-shape filled with a texture/image being the background at that position.

[image: Image that explains it better maybe] (The meshes I want to use are obviously more complex than a sphere)

What is the best way to achieve such an effect? I thought about either projection mapping as to sort of projecting the background texture onto the mesh from the cameras perspective. Or is maybe a stencil buffer the way to go? From what I've read, the support of it is not so high at this point. Maybe there is also a way simpler method to solve this issue that I've missed?

Comment: I know of zero WebGL implementations that don't support a stencil buffer. You have to request it though. `var gl = someCanvas.getContext("webgl", {stencil: true});`

Comment: Stencil is part of the core spec, if not available on the drawing buffer(which as gman mentioned is a rare to non existing case) you can create a framebuffer with a `DEPTH_STENCIL` attachment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There tons of ways to do this, which is best for you is up to you.

### Use the stencil buffer

Draw your mesh into the stencil buffer then draw your image with the stencil test set so it only draws where the mesh was drawn

```js
var geoVS = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
var geoFS = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);  // doesn't matter. We're only using the stencil  
}
`;
var imgVS = `
attribute vec4 position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = position.xy * .5 + .5;  // only works if position is -1 <-> +1 quad
}
`;
var imgFS = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, v_texcoord);  
}
`;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl", {stencil: true});
const geoPrgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [geoVS, geoFS]);
const imgPrgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [imgVS, imgFS]);

const geoBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);
const quadBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);

const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8873/18598400202_3af67ef38f_z_d.jpg",
  crossOrigin: "",
  flipY: true,
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  var fov = Math.PI * .25;
  var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  var zNear = 0.1;
  var zFar = 10;
  var mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  mat = m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -3]);
  mat = m4.rotateX(mat, time * 0.81);
  mat = m4.rotateZ(mat, time * 0.77);
  
  // draw geometry to generate stencil
  gl.useProgram(geoPrgInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, geoPrgInfo, geoBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(geoPrgInfo, {
    matrix: mat,
  });

  // write 1 to stencil
  gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
  gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
  gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.REPLACE);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, geoBufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
  // draw image where stencil is set
  gl.useProgram(imgPrgInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, imgPrgInfo, quadBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(imgPrgInfo, {
    tex: tex,
  });
  
  gl.stencilFunc(gl.EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
  gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, quadBufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
   
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

### Use the depth buffer

Draw your mesh into the depth buffer then draw your image with the depth function set so it only draws where the mesh was drawn.

```js
var geoVS = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
var geoFS = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);  // doesn't matter. We're only using the stencil  
}
`;
var imgVS = `
attribute vec4 position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = position.xy * .5 + .5;  // only works if position is -1 <-> +1 quad
}
`;
var imgFS = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, v_texcoord);  
}
`;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl", {stencil: true});
const geoPrgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [geoVS, geoFS]);
const imgPrgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [imgVS, imgFS]);

const geoBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);
const quadBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);

const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8873/18598400202_3af67ef38f_z_d.jpg",
  crossOrigin: "",
  flipY: true,
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clearDepth(0);  // clear depth to 0 (normally it's 1)
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
  var fov = Math.PI * .25;
  var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  var zNear = 0.1;
  var zFar = 10;
  var mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  mat = m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -3]);
  mat = m4.rotateX(mat, time * 0.81);
  mat = m4.rotateZ(mat, time * 0.77);
  
  // draw geometry to generate depth
  gl.useProgram(geoPrgInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, geoPrgInfo, geoBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(geoPrgInfo, {
    matrix: mat,
  });

  gl.depthFunc(gl.ALWAYS);  // we only care about silhouette
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, geoBufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
  // draw image where depth is set
  gl.useProgram(imgPrgInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, imgPrgInfo, quadBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(imgPrgInfo, {
    tex: tex,
  });

  gl.depthFunc(gl.LESS);
  // this quad is drawn at z = 0 which is in the middle Z wize. Should probably
  // make it 1 so it's in the back but it's working as is so too lazy to
  // change
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, quadBufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
   
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

### Use CSS

Set the canvas's CSS background to an image. Clear the canvas to some color, draw your mesh with 0,0,0,0 to cut a hole.

```js
var geoVS = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
var geoFS = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0);   
}
`;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl", {stencil: true});
const geoPrgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [geoVS, geoFS]);

const geoBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1); // clear to white
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  var fov = Math.PI * .25;
  var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  var zNear = 0.1;
  var zFar = 10;
  var mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  mat = m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -3]);
  mat = m4.rotateX(mat, time * 0.81);
  mat = m4.rotateZ(mat, time * 0.77);
  
  // draw in 0,0,0,0 to cut a whole in the canvas to the HTML/CSS
  // defined background
  gl.useProgram(geoPrgInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, geoPrgInfo, geoBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(geoPrgInfo, {
    matrix: mat,
  });

  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, geoBufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
     
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; 
  background-image: url(https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8873/18598400202_3af67ef38f_z_d.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

### Generate a texture mask

Draw the mesh to a texture through framebuffer to generate a silhouette in the texture. Use that texture as input to another shader as a mask

```js
var geoVS = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
var geoFS = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1); 
}
`;
var imgVS = `
attribute vec4 position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = position.xy * .5 + .5;  // only works if position is -1 <-> +1 quad
}
`;
var imgFS = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D colorTex;
uniform sampler2D maskTex;
void main() {
  vec4 color = texture2D(colorTex, v_texcoord);
  vec4 mask = texture2D(maskTex, v_texcoord);
  gl_FragColor = color * mask;  
}
`;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl", {stencil: true});
const geoPrgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [geoVS, geoFS]);
const imgPrgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [imgVS, imgFS]);

const geoBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);
const quadBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);

const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8873/18598400202_3af67ef38f_z_d.jpg",
  crossOrigin: "",
  flipY: true,
});

// with no options creates a framebuffer with an RGBA8 texture
// and depth buffer
const fbi = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  if (twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas)) {
    // with no argument will resize to the canvas size
    twgl.resizeFramebufferInfo(gl, fbi);
  }

  // calls gl.bindFramebuffer and gl.viewport
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, fbi);
  
  // first draw the geometry to the texture
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  var fov = Math.PI * .25;
  var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  var zNear = 0.1;
  var zFar = 10;
  var mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  mat = m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -3]);
  mat = m4.rotateX(mat, time * 0.81);
  mat = m4.rotateZ(mat, time * 0.77);
  
  gl.useProgram(geoPrgInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, geoPrgInfo, geoBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(geoPrgInfo, {
    matrix: mat,
  });

  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, geoBufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  // the texture now is black (0,0,0,0) where there's nothing and (1,1,1,1)
  // where are geometry was drawn

  // calls gl.bindFramebuffer and gl.viewport
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, null);
  
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    
  // draw image using our texture as a mask
  gl.useProgram(imgPrgInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, imgPrgInfo, quadBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(imgPrgInfo, {
    colorTex: tex,
    maskTex: fbi.attachments[0],
  });
  
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, quadBufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
   
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Personally I'd probably use the last one as it's more flexible. You can use any technique to generate the mask. The mask will have levels (as in you can set it to 0.5 to get a 50/50 blend). That means you can get an antialiased each if you want. You can mask each color separate amounts.  You could easily blend between 2 images, etc. You could add other effects like [displacement maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059618/128511) etc to the final pass.

Here's an example of rendering a cube in shades of gray and using the result to blend 2 images.

```js
var geoVS = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
uniform mat4 matrix;
varying vec3 v_normal;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
  v_normal = (matrix * vec4(normal, 0)).xyz;
}
`;
var geoFS = `
precision mediump float;
uniform vec3 u_lightDir;
varying vec3 v_normal;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(dot(normalize(v_normal), u_lightDir) * .5 + .5); 
}
`;
var imgVS = `
attribute vec4 position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = position.xy * .5 + .5;  // only works if position is -1 <-> +1 quad
}
`;
var imgFS = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D color1Tex;
uniform sampler2D color2Tex;
uniform sampler2D maskTex;
void main() {
  // it probably doesn't make sense to use the same
  // texcoords for all 3 textures but I'm lazy
  vec4 color1 = texture2D(color1Tex, v_texcoord);
  vec4 color2 = texture2D(color2Tex, v_texcoord);
  vec4 mask = texture2D(maskTex, v_texcoord);
  gl_FragColor = mix(color1, color2, mask);  
}
`;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const v3 = twgl.v3;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl", {stencil: true});
const geoPrgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [geoVS, geoFS]);
const imgPrgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [imgVS, imgFS]);

const geoBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);
const quadBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);

const textures = twgl.createTextures(gl, {
  tex1: {
    src: "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8873/18598400202_3af67ef38f_z_d.jpg",
    crossOrigin: "",
    flipY: true,
  },
  tex2: {
    src: "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/339/18414821420_e3d0a8ec5f_z_d.jpg",
    crossOrigin: "",
    flipY: true,
  },
});

// with no options creates a framebuffer with an RGBA8 texture
// and depth buffer
const fbi = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  if (twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas)) {
    // with no argument will resize to the canvas size
    twgl.resizeFramebufferInfo(gl, fbi);
  }

  // calls gl.bindFramebuffer and gl.viewport
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, fbi);
  
  // first draw the geometry to the texture
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
  var fov = Math.PI * .25;
  var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  var zNear = 0.1;
  var zFar = 10;
  var mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  mat = m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -3]);
  mat = m4.rotateX(mat, time * 0.81);
  mat = m4.rotateZ(mat, time * 0.77);
  
  gl.useProgram(geoPrgInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, geoPrgInfo, geoBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(geoPrgInfo, {
    matrix: mat,
    u_lightDir: v3.normalize([1, 2, 3]),
  });

  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, geoBufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  // the texture now is black (0,0,0,0) where there's nothing and (1,1,1,1)
  // where are geometry was drawn

  // calls gl.bindFramebuffer and gl.viewport
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, null);
  
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    
  // draw image using our texture as a mask
  gl.useProgram(imgPrgInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, imgPrgInfo, quadBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(imgPrgInfo, {
    color1Tex: textures.tex1,
    color2Tex: textures.tex2,
    maskTex: fbi.attachments[0],
  });
  
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, quadBufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
   
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

In general you can probably achieve many more effects using the texture mask but it really depends on your goal.

Comment: Hi @gman, thanks for your answer. It got me further in the right direction but what you describe would do the opposite thing of what I am trying to achieve (or maybe I am misunderstanding). I want the background texture to only draw where the mesh would be. I've made a little explanation image [here](http://i.imgur.com/YhQI1BUl.jpg).

Comment: Give it a go and you'll see this does exactly what you want.

Comment: Every method I've suggested will do exactly as your image depicts

Answer (score 0):

Both approach can work.

The 'projection' one is probably more efficient and straightforward. It work with one single pass. You just need to substitute the classic UVs coordinates by the screen coordinates of vertices, in your vertex shader.

```
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main( void ){
  // whatever how gl_Position is compute
  gl_Position    = uMVP * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);

  // vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
  // replace the standard UVs by the vertex screen position
  vTexCoord = .5 * ( gl_Position.xy / gl_Position.w ) + .5;
}
```

You still need to tweak thoses texture coordinates to respect screen/texture aspect ratio, scale etc.